# How to put arrow icon next to text in QToolButton QT C++

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

I am using QToolButton as dropdown button (but not setting QMenu to QToolButton). On click of button, I am showing my customize menu which is not QMenu based class. I want to put a down arrow on button.

I tried stylesheet and other thing but icon showing before text. I want down arrow after text.

like

[image]

how to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the arrow as a Unicode caracter, for example ['BLACK DOWN-POINTING TRIANGLE'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25bc/index.htm) or '[BLACK DOWN-POINTING SMALL TRIANGLE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25be/index.htm)'.

That would give you something like "Modify ▼"

Comment: Thanks, It is working. Although it solved my problem but still what I want, I am not getting.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `toolButtonStyle` property to `ToolButtonTextUnderIcon` in `QToolButton`.